# Does the Magic Bedroll benefit stack on top of a heal check?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, rests

Do the benefits from magic bedroll and heal check stack for the HP recovery from rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they stack.

Heal requires bandages and like, so it's some sort of medical attention that double the normal rate of healing.

> Providing long-term care means treating a wounded person for a day or
>   more. If your Heal check is successful, the patient recovers hit
>   points or ability score points (lost to ability damage) at twice the
>   normal rate: 2 hit points per level for a full 8 hours of rest in a
>   day, or 4 hit points per level for each full day of complete rest; 2
>   ability score points for a full 8 hours of rest in a day, or 4 ability
>   score points for each full day of complete rest.
>
> You can tend as many as six patients at a time. You need a few items
>   and supplies (bandages, salves, and so on) that are easy to come by in
>   settled lands.

Magic Bedroll (MIC pg 163) gives HPs for sleeping inside **on top** of normal recover.

So they stack because the skill acts on the normal recovery rate and the magic item gives something on top of that normal rate. They are unrelated. They just works in conditions often associate (rest and sleeping). You can rest and receive medical attention (heal check) even when you are sleeping inside a bedroll. The check improves your natural healing and the magic bedroll gives some 'bonus' HP. We have two different causes (check and item) for different effects (improve natural healing and recover HPs) but to the same result (increase your HPs).

Comment: I agree with this answer, but since this is a rules question, I think it could be improved by including some mention of the restrictions on stacking in D&D 3.5 (found [here](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm)), and an explanation of why those restrictions don't apply in this case.  From a rules perspective, the stacking rules are why these two forms of healing both apply.

Comment: In this case I don't think the stacking rules come in action... we have two things acting on two different values... in other words they don't stack because they are two different things